# On my HTML website, why does changing my text-alignment within a paragraph tag automatically close the paragraph tag once rendered in a browser?

Tags: html

This is a very small HTML question that I am sure you guys will answer quickly.  I post things on my website like this

```
<div id="content">
     <p>
          <hh>Header text here</hh>
          Post information here, text and stuff.
     </p>

     <p>
          <hh>Header 2 text here</hh>
          Post 2 information here, text and stuff.
     </p>
</div>
```

but when I try to insert a `<center>` or alight left tag, the `<p>` closes automatically, and everything after the `<center>` tag is outside the paragraph box.  I used inspect-element in firefox, and I can see it closes with a `</p>` that I never typed, right before any calls to centered text.

For example:

```
<p>
     <hh>Header 2 text here</hh>
     Post 2 information here, text and stuff.
     <center>This text is centered</center>
</p>
```

is rendering as this:

```
<p>
     <hh>Header 2 text here</hh>
     Post 2 information here, text and stuff.
</p>
<center>This text is centered</center>
</p>
```

This is really frustrating, and if someone could help me out that would be amazing.  using `<div align-right>` also doesn't work.  If it helps, I can set the entire `<p>` to align any way and it works.
It ONLY breaks when I differ from the set orientation within that tag.

Comment: What is your DOCTYPE? Recent versions of HTML doesn't support center-tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From w3school :

> Use CSS to center text!
>
> The  tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.
>
> The  element is deprecated in HTML 4.01.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

It is because center acts like a p. And you cannot put a p in a p.

EDIT : To answer to your comment, you should probably do this :

```
<p>
     <hh>Header 2 text here</hh>
     Post 2 information here, text and stuff.
     <span>This text is centered</span>
<p>
```

And in your css add this

```
#content p span { display:block; text-align:center; }
```

(It also works with an a tag if you want it)

Comment: Ok, so I am using 4.01.  However, even when I use CSS to define the (#content p c {}) as a center aligned object, the [c] tag doesn't work at all.

Comment: What is c ? Are you sure it is not #c (for an id) or .c (for a class) ? If the code is the same as the one you posted, you should try #content p {text-align:center;}

Comment: I have the '#content' for the div I put all of the paragraph tags in as shown above.  I define everything for how a paragraph looks in '#content p' and I defined the new center attribute as '#content p c'.  I figured the c shouldn't be on its own or it will be just the same as using 'center'... am I wrong here?

Comment: I guess what I was missing was display:block then.  Because that is the only think I did not have.

Comment: Text-align only works on block (because the browser defines a width with this and can do the maths to align the element). Just like auto margin left/right only works with a width defined.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you can't use a hh-tag in a p-tag then. (Not sure, but that's mostly)